# Using the verb "prefer" with the "perfect gerund"

Tags: gerunds, perfect-constructions

Is it OK to use *prefer* with the perfect gerund?

1. I would prefer having travelled by car last month.
2. I would prefer having been watching TV for the last twenty minutes.

Comment: I think most native speakers would write something like : "I would have preferred traveling by car last month".

Comment: Right. Also _I would have preferred watching TV_.  Get the auxiliary verbs as high up the tree as possible. Once you're past the main verb, you don't want to trip on complex VPs coming downstairs.

Answer (score 2):

## Simplify, simplify, simplify!

Given:

1. I **would prefer having travelled** by car last month.
2. I **would prefer having been watching** TV for the last twenty minutes.

Your sentence (2) is at least borderline ungrammatical and quite possibly entirely so.

Your sentence (1) is grammatical but unwieldy.

As John Lawler suggests,
you should promote the auxiliary verbs as far to the left as you can
to get them out of the way and simplify the remaining verb constructions to their right.

### Step 1: *Would prefer having travelled* > *would have preferred travelling*

The easiest transformation here is for us to move the *have* auxiliary to the left so that it falls **before** *prefer* instead of **after** it. This way you have both auxiliaries together, which is how we prefer things.

Now it’s just plain *have* not *having*, and we switch *travelled* to *travelling* to preserve the *‑ing* aspect if we’d like. We’ll use contraction of auxiliaries which is mandatory in all but the most formal of spoken registers, and common enough in casual written ones, too.

3. I would **have** preferred travelling by car last month.
4. I’d **have** preferred travelling by car last month.
5. I would**’ve** preferred travelling by car last month.
6. I’d**’ve** preferred travelling by car last month.

### Step 2: *Would have preferred travelling* > *would have preferred to travel*

You can also use a *to*-infinitive for your travel instead of an *‑ing* verb for it:

7. I would have preferred **to travel** by car last month.
8. I’d have preferred **to travel** by car last month.
9. I would’ve preferred **to travel** by car last month.
10. I’d’ve preferred **to travel** by car last month.

### Step 3: *Would have preferred travelling* > *would rather have travelled*

Finally, you can use the original **non-modal** sense of *will* as the main
verb rather than as an auxiliary verb.  When you do that, it means the same
thing as *want* or *wish* more commonly does today, and adding *rather* to make *will rather* in the present tense or *would rather* in the past tense
turns it into the equivalent of your own *prefer* verb.

11. I **would rather** have travelled by car last month.
12. I**’d rather** have travelled by car last month.

### Step 4: *Would rather have travelled* > *would have rather travelled*

This also presents one more possibility for promoting the auxiliary *have* still further to the left once contraction is involved:

13. I **would’ve** rather travelled by car last month.
14. I**’d’ve** rather travelled by car last month.

### Step 5: “Would that it had been so!”

The construction *“Would that ...!”* means the same thing as *“If only ...!”* means, but in a more formal or literary register. It sounds rather old-fashioned, the sort of thing you might hear in oratorical speeches (perhaps from people familiar with Ancient Greek’s **optative** mood used for expressing wishes):

15. **Would that** I had travelled by car last month!
16. **Would that** I’d travelled by car last month!

### Step 6: “If wishes were fishes, they’d travel by water-car.”

Finally, the simplest way to say all that is by reducing it all to the simple verb *wish*. Notice that the auxiliary in the subordinate clause now needs to be in the past tense.

17. I **wish** I **had** travelled by car last month.
18. I **wish** I**’d** travelled by car last month.

I hope you recognize how much better that final sentence (18) is than your initial sentence (1) was. It is far more natural in our mouths. It’s also a lot harder to get wrong, whether in saying it or in understanding it said.

## Summary

Given the choice of several possible variants, you should nearly always choose simpler verb constructions over complex ones. After all, native speakers certainly do so, and not for just one reason alone, either.